# "Hello TensorFlow!" using the C API

Tags: dll, tensorflow, c-api

For learning purposes, how to code this Python example using the TensorFlow C API ?

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("hello TensorFlow!")
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I have tried it this way:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include "c_api.h"

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
  TF_Graph * graph = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_SessionOptions * options = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Status * status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_Session * session = TF_NewSession( graph, options, status );
  char hello[] = "Hello TensorFlow!";
  TF_Tensor * tensor = TF_AllocateTensor( TF_STRING, 0, 0, 8 + TF_StringEncodedSize( strlen( hello ) ) );
  TF_OperationDescription * operationDescription = TF_NewOperation( graph, "Const", "hello" );
  TF_Operation * operation; 
  struct TF_Output * output;

  TF_StringEncode( hello, strlen( hello ), 8 + ( char * ) TF_TensorData( tensor ), TF_StringEncodedSize( strlen( hello ) ), status );
  TF_SetAttrTensor( operationDescription, "value", tensor, status );
  TF_SetAttrType( operationDescription, "dtype", TF_TensorType( tensor ) );
  operation = TF_FinishOperation( operationDescription, status );

  output->oper = operation;
  output->index = 0;

  TF_SessionRun( session, 0,
                 0, 0, 0,  // Inputs
                 output, &tensor, 1,  // Outputs
                 &operation, 1,  // Operations
                 0, status );

  printf( "%i", TF_GetCode( status ) );

  TF_CloseSession( session, status );
  TF_DeleteSession( session, status );
  TF_DeleteStatus( status );
  TF_DeleteSessionOptions( options );  

  return 0;
}
```

I am testing it on Windows using the `TensorFlow.dll` from:
http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-libtensorflow-windows/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/lib_package/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64.zip

The above code GPFs on the `TF_SessionRun()` call. Once we find a solution for that, how to retrieve the output ? Should a different tensor be used for the 
output ? The above code reuses it in both the output and the operation.

many thanks

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` in C?  What is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 9):

There was a bug to solve beside the offset initialization. This version seems to work fine:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "c_api.h"

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
  TF_Graph * graph = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_SessionOptions * options = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Status * status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_Session * session = TF_NewSession( graph, options, status );
  char hello[] = "Hello TensorFlow!";
  TF_Tensor * tensor = TF_AllocateTensor( TF_STRING, 0, 0, 8 + TF_StringEncodedSize( strlen( hello ) ) );
  TF_Tensor * tensorOutput;
  TF_OperationDescription * operationDescription = TF_NewOperation( graph, "Const", "hello" );
  TF_Operation * operation; 
  struct TF_Output output;

  TF_StringEncode( hello, strlen( hello ), 8 + ( char * ) TF_TensorData( tensor ), TF_StringEncodedSize( strlen( hello ) ), status );
  memset( TF_TensorData( tensor ), 0, 8 );
  TF_SetAttrTensor( operationDescription, "value", tensor, status );
  TF_SetAttrType( operationDescription, "dtype", TF_TensorType( tensor ) );
  operation = TF_FinishOperation( operationDescription, status );

  output.oper = operation;
  output.index = 0;

  TF_SessionRun( session, 0,
                 0, 0, 0,  // Inputs
                 &output, &tensorOutput, 1,  // Outputs
                 &operation, 1,  // Operations
                 0, status );

  printf( "status code: %i\n", TF_GetCode( status ) );
  printf( "%s\n", ( ( char * ) TF_TensorData( tensorOutput ) ) + 9 );

  TF_CloseSession( session, status );
  TF_DeleteSession( session, status );
  TF_DeleteStatus( status );
  TF_DeleteSessionOptions( options );  

  return 0;
}
```

Do we have to delete the tensorOutput ? Not sure why we have to add 9 (instead of 8) to get the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`TF_STRING` tensors are encoded using the format [described here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L210). In your code, you accounted for space (8 bytes) to encode the one offset, but didn't actually initialize it. To do that, you'd want to add something like:

memset(TF_TensorData(tensor), 0, 8);

Before the call to `TF_SetAttrTensor`, as that will set the "offset" of the string element to 0 (which the where you're encoding the one string value).

To your second question: You aren't actually re-using the same `tensor` pointer. The [comments for `TF_SessionRun`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1076) suggest that `TF_SessionRun` is allocating a new `TF_Tensor` object that the caller takes ownership of. So, in your code snippet, the `tensor` variable is being overwritten to point to a newly allocated tensor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I wasn't aware that the string offset had to be initialized too.

Answer (score 0):

The example will work on Linux with TensorFlow installed as described here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c with changed `include` directives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>
```

To build it is enough to execute

```
gcc hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf
```

as it was said in TensorFlow docs.